# How to warn if code contains %s formatting

Tags: python, pre-commit.com

I use Python since 2001, and I am very used to `%s` string formatting.

In my current environment code should be formatted with f-strings.

How to automatically check my code, so I don't accidentally use my old habit?

Comment: Since you need to wire up some form of automation to run the check, why not go forward and make that automation to actually convert all format strings to f-strings with https://github.com/ikamensh/flynt ?

Comment: @rasjani this is a huge code base, cleaning the whole thing is not my current task. But I can suggest this at the next meeting.

Answer (score 1):

I use pyupgrade as a pre-commit hook https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade

Sample .pre-commit-config.yaml:

```
-   repo: https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade
    rev: v2.10.0
    hooks:
    -   id: pyupgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [pre-commit.com](//pre-commit.com) config

`.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```yaml
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: dont-use-%s-formatting
        name: Do not use %s formatting any more
        entry: \%s
        language: pygrep
        types: [text]
```

Comment: Is that just a regex to detect literal `%s`? If so, there are a lot of things it would miss (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). Also you still need to use `printf`-style format strings for e.g. logging.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, this is just a regex detecting `%s`. Of course this won't catch a lot of other old-string-formatting, but `%s` is the one which used the most. And there could be false-positives, but then I can use `SKIP=...  git commit`. I like the solution. Do you know a better solution?

Comment: A brief Google suggests e.g. https://pypi.org/project/flake8-printf-formatting/